# Testcontainers for .NET crashs on container start

Tags: c#, .net, testcontainers

I am using Testcontainers to set up integration tests but my container dies as soon as it starts.

Here is the code:

```cs
public class IntegTest : IAsyncLifetime
{
    private readonly TestcontainerDatabase _dbContainer =
        new TestcontainersBuilder<PostgreSqlTestcontainer>()
            .WithDatabase(new PostgreSqlTestcontainerConfiguration
            {
                Database = "db",
                Username = "user",
                Password = "pass1"
            }).Build();
    
    [Fact]
    public async Task myTest()
    {
        // Test Code here
    }
     
    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await _dbContainer.StartAsync();
    }

    public new async Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        await _dbContainer.DisposeAsync();
    }
}
```

There is no error in the output console except the following:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

The container comes up for a second and then shuts down. The code never enters `myTest()` but `DisposeAsync()` gets called as soon as the container shuts down.

NuGet Testcontainers version: 1.6.0,
.NET version: 6.0

Comment: The version `1.6.0` seems wrong (is outdated). Can you please use `2.3.0` or later? Can you add the stack trace if you still have issues?

Comment: Using the correct version worked. Thanks!